# AngularJS: How to implement Live TimeAgo filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I would like to have AngularJS filter timeAgo that should be applied for a timestamp to show time passed from timestamp. That's an easy one:

```
filter('timeago', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Date.now() - input;
  }
});
```

But when I wanted to make it **LIVE**(when user on the page - we update the value each second/each digest) it appeared to be not that easy. We don't change input value, so filter is not recalculated.
Is it possible to make it recalculable each second without adding extra parameters?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/cupj5dee/) example.

- I'm not looking for ready libraries (like angular-moment). It's more interesting for me how to implement such concept in AngularJs.

Comment: Can you explain why u want to make such filter not a directive? Are there any other example of usage?

Comment: it should do the same as angular-moment amTimeAgo filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the filters are now stateless, to make it work for this filter you will need to do:

```
function timeagoFilter(input) {
  return Date.now() - input;
}

timeagoFilter.$stateful = true;

return timeagoFilter;
```

but personally I'd turn it into a directive and change the value with plain javascript - if it's just for display purposes - since it's easy to mess up digest cycle and make the app performance degrade

Comment: great! that's what I was looking for

Comment: this filter wont work if your digest takes more than ~1ms. Actually it ends with $rootScope:infdig error.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I think you did something wrong if you got infinite digest error

Comment: no it is quite obvious 1st digest filter return i.e.10. Second digest - 11. Third 12. Etc. Values are never same. >> error

Comment: You might be confusing few things and what digest does